# What does a call on queue.join() in main thread do to non-main threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

My code is as below,

```
import time, queue, threading

def washer(dishes, dish_queue): 
    for dish in dishes: 
        print ("Washing", dish) 
        time.sleep(1) 
        dish_queue.put(dish)

def dryer(dish_queue): 
    while True: 
        dish = dish_queue.get() 
        print("Drying", dish) 
        time.sleep(2) 
        dish_queue.task_done()
        print('dryer')

dish_queue = queue.Queue()
for n in range(2): 
    dryer_thread = threading.Thread(target=dryer, args=(dish_queue,))
    dryer_thread.start()

dishes = ['salad', 'bread', 'entree', 'desert'] 
washer(dishes, dish_queue) 
dish_queue.join()
```

From my understanding on the queue module documentation, dish_queue.join() will block the main thread until the count of unfinished tasks (here is undried dishes) back to 0. But I wonder what has happened to the 2 dryer_thread.

I found that if I run function `dryer` on an empty `dish_queue` in main program, the program is stuck (BTW, is this the so-called block from dish_queue.get()?) . So if `dish_queue.join()` unblocks the main thread, do the 2 dryer_thread also unblock and free the memory? What does ***block*** mean anyway in the queue doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your main question is nothing.

For a longer answer, here are two concurrency graphs, one without wait:
[image]

And one with:
[image]

As you can see, at the beginning both the two dryer threads are in a lock, which is, as you correctly understood, is `get()`'s block. Now, in the first case the main thread finishes after finishing the washer function. When adding the `dish_queue.join()` the main thread waits for the dish_queue to end all the tasks. So when you say that `join()` unblocks the main thread, it means that it removes it's own block. As you can notice, the other threads are totally unaffected by it and remain blocked.

As for what is block, it's when a thread or a process waits for input from outside the thread, or in this case, waiting for the an element in the queue. In case that you want to stop the other threads, you'll need to either add a timeout to `get()` (which will throw an exception and kill the thread), or kill them after the `dish_queue.join()`.

Comment: Besides setting a timeout value, what do you suggest for terminating the other threads? I'm not sure if setting other threads as daemon works. Also, if I do not change my code and just keep them blocking, do they really consume my memory?

Comment: BTW, what concurrency monitor are you using? It's classy!

Comment: Generally, a thread with a block is the same as a sleeping thread. It won't release it's memory, but won't consume any additional resources as well, so basically it depends on whether you'll need the thread in the future. To be noted, the threads will be there as long as the main thread is active, so you shouldn't open new ones and rather add new elements to the existing queue.


I'm using pyCharm, which is a great all around IDE.

Comment: This phrase `it won't release it's memory, but won't consume any additional resources as well` though correct from the application POV, isn't entirely true from the OS POV. The OS CPU scheduler would put the blocked process into the `wait queue`. Also the memory that it possesses is `virtual` in nature (on most OSes these days unless you are specifically  using a non paging OS, typical of some RTOSes and real mode firmware on rudimentary 8 bit devices). So the actual memory that was being used by the blocked process (aka the working set in windows terminology) would be released to the system